# What is the point of "de" in this sentence?

Tags: prépositions, de

I'm reading a French article to practice my reading skills and I've come across this sentence:

> Les scientifiques ont constaté qu'une personne seule a un risque accru de 29% de souffrir d'une crise cardiaque ou d'une angine de poitrine et 32% plus de risque d'être victime d'un AVC

I understand it pretty clearly, however, what is the point of "de" in "de souffrir..." and "d'être victime..."?

I understand that some verbs have de go after the infinitive, like for example permettre de, however I haven't heard of de going before the infinitive verb or anything like that.

Could someone explain to me why this is? Is there a rule for this use of de or something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

That's the very same rule you already mentioned about *permettre de*.

Here the expression is *avoir un risque de*, i.e. *risquer de*.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that! I thought de was there for other purposes for some reason... Didn't realize it was actually part of the expression. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to French:
*What kind **of** risk ?

A risk **of** suffering...*

The same in French:
*Quel genre **de** risque ?

Le risque **de** souffrir...*